# Will Apple approve an app which internally uses a library developed by Google?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using the `GDataXML` library developed by Google as part of their Objective-C client library. As its Google’s XML processing library and I heard that Apple don't allow to use any third party libraries in app, will they allow this one?. (I am using this library because many iOS geeks suggest to use it.)

Comment: `Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected`   GDataXML is public api. so thats fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use any third party libraries which dont perform private api calls. There are many third party libraries that are used in iOS development. Apple will approve it if it is not calling private APIs.

Answer (score 3):

Apple provided a review guidelines for developers to follow when submitting app to app store.. check [here](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) for the guidelines.

**2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected**

GDataXML is public api so that should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Where did you hear you can't use third party libraries? There are lots of people using third party libraries all the time. Many apps do so. Take as an example the AFNetworking library https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking , a very common third party library for network connections.